# Getter and setter for List

Tags: java, list, setter, getter

```
class MipRequest{

    private List<String> MipIDs=null;   

    public List<String> getMipIDs() {       
        return MipIDs;  
    }   

    public void setMipIDs(List<String> mipIDs) {
        MipIDs = mipIDs;
    }

}
```

How can i call the get function?

Comment: How are you calling `set` method?

Comment: if(mipObj!=null)
   { 
    mipObj.setMipIDs(storedReqID);} @RohitJain

Comment: mipObj is instance of MipRequest

Answer (score 0):

You could call it by using object instance like:

```
MipRequest mipRequest = new MipRequest();
//set list...
List<String> mipIds = mipRequest.getMipIDs();
//further business logic
```

Comment: How can i iterate for printing??

Comment: I am doing as below but it is not working 'code' Iterator<String> it = mipRequest.getMipIDs().iterator();
  while(it.hasNext())
  {
   String dtsID= it.next();
   System.out.println("Inside iterator");
   System.out.println("dtsID : "+dtsID);
    
  }'code' @SMA

Comment: And then what's the issue?

Comment: It is not printing @SMA

Comment: have you populated list? if yes how?